How to extract value from nested array
I have written below code for extract the "object vector" value, but I am unable to get the value.
mycode:
pm.collectionVariables.set('newObjectVector', responseData.data.object_vector);
pm.expect(responseData.data.object_vector, "object vector").to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get('newObjectVector'));

Response body:
{
    "message": "Object Updated",
    "data": {
        "lor_object_id": "17c4801c-8ca5-491a-a5e6-f4ab926cdbee",
        "object_version": "00b13753-7ef8-42e0-bad5-b13de2f27c7b",
        "tenant_id": "b406c3de-8cbd-4273-aa2a-58565bfa50fb",
        "chunk_id": "9fb5f5f7-d351-40b6-816c-95458808b0be",
        "text": "invoice Principal Cambridgeshire synthesizing Nature encompasses the physical world and all living organisms within it, including plants, animals, landscapes, and natural phenomena. It is characterized by its diversity, beauty, and the interdependent relationships between living organisms and their environment.",
        "object_vector": [
            [
                0.01898559369146824,
                -0.038494404405355453,
                -0.008875240571796894,
                0.010678712278604507,
                -0.049301765859127045,
                -0.008310616947710514,   
                 0.05476781725883484,
                -0.043765418231487274
            ]
        ],
        "metadata": {}
    }
}

I need to extract object vector from the above body in the postman

Your object_vector key has an array as its value so you need to target the value with its array index.
Array indexes start at zero, so it would be..
const response = pm.response.json();
console.log(response.data.object_vector[0]);

The value is also an array, and I don't know if you want a single element from that array, or the whole array.  (The above is the whole array).

However, your test doesn't really make any sense, as its comparing the response with itself.  You also need to wrap the assertion in an test block.
pm.test("object vector matches", () => {
    let newObjectVector = response.data.object_vector[0];
    pm.expect(response.data.object_vector[0], "object vector").to.eql(newObjectVector);
    // this test doesn't make any sense as its just comparing itself
});

